# Should I vote to "reopen" a question that now has more details but would now be closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Here is a question on SO that has been closed as lacking details and I see why that is:

[Python List Doesn't Preserve Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70666379/python-list-doesnt-preserve-order)

While reading the question, I see the author has posted addition information in the comments explaining more about the problem and I see that there are now two votes to "reopen" the question.

The author has opened a second question that is a much better question dealing directly with the actual issue rather than this one and it is a link in a comment to that question that I feel is calling people's attention to a problem that was initially hidden.

[PrettyTable Not working with some languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70666572/prettytable-not-working-with-some-languages)

I'm not sure I would now vote to reopen the question but even if I did, I would then be tempted to vote to close it as a duplicate of the new better question.

**My question:**

Should I vote to reopen an improved question with additional information only to then vote to close it as a duplicate?

Comment: You'll get mixed opinions on this. On the one hand, it requires up to 6 votes to just end up in the same state, a closed question. On the other, a better sign post is created. Some would say yes, reopen and reclose, others will say no, just leave a comment pointing to the duplicate.

Comment: Pfwoa, this is going to be a non-consensus case for sure. I can envision at least two camps that are going to be pulling on either side of the rope. Side A: no, no need to reopen something that is already closed if it is just going to be closed again. Side B: yes reopen and vote to close, precision is important.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the question to contain a minimal reproduceable example since the output that op gets is still missing. It's also unclear which language ops system is using or even which command line they are using. That's not an answer to the general case, but this specific question should stay closed as needing debugging details.

Comment: Do the OP a favour and get the question deleted ASAP. It's still in pretty bad shape and basically a misunderstanding; the chances of someone wondering whether a "list preserves order" *due to the same underlying cause* are slim. Keeping it available *and drawing attention via meta* will just garner a needlessly negative reaction for the question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The original particularly poor question remains closed. I'm not sure how I would advocate for deletion. I'm not sure I have that permission (yet). Should I flag it for Mod Attention?

Comment: My stance on this is if the original close reason is resolved, then the post should not stay closed as such. Wrong close reasons (or those that became obsolete) skew SEDE stats. It also sends the wrong message for users that stumble upon the post. Finally, it also teaches the OP that no matter what they do, the post will stay closed as we justify the means by their ends.

Comment: @OlegValter Yeah precision is important :)

Comment: @Gimby now we only need to wait till the other side joins in for the fun times :)